# Why does require('underscore') return undefined when executed at the node.js REPL?

Tags: node.js, include, require, underscore.js

When I run node in my console and type `var _ = require('underscore');`, `_` ends up undefined. If I put the same code in a file and execute it, the underscore library gets included as expected.

```
$ node
> var _ = require('underscore');
> console.log(_)
undefined // underscore library does not load
> var async = require('async');
undefined
> console.log(async) // async library does
{ noConflict: [Function],
  nextTick: [Function],
  forEach: [Function],
...
>
```

But the same code in a .js file executed as `node test.js` shows both libraries loading as expected. What's going on?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Node repl binds `_` to the value of the last evaluated input; which overwrites your `_` binding in `var _ = ...;`. Also see [the node.js documentation on the repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features).

This is true no matter what replaces `...`, for example:

```
$ node
> var _ = "any value";
undefined
> _
undefined
```

Comment: this was driving me crazy!

Comment: It was driving me crazy too. I want to mention that this answer applies to lodash as well as underscore.